# Location of the center of the map-fragment - Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, location, mapfragment

I need to get the location of the center of my map-fragment. Of course it is not the center of the screen. I want to do something every time this location changes.

Every time the user moves/scrolls the map, I need the location of the center of my fragment and do something with them.

So, any Idea of how can I do that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

EDIT:

So I implemented OnCameraChangeListener and added onCameraChange but it never executes:

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
    Log.v("tag", "onCameraChange");

    mLatitude = arg0.target.latitude;
    mLongitude = arg0.target.longitude;
    Log.v("tag", "onCameraChange  "+mLatitude+" "+mLongitude);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().target
```

Comment: Aha, I think this should work. But how can I execute a method overy time the cameraposition is changed?

Comment: Just implement the `OnCameraChangeListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html which provides the method `onCameraChange(CameraPosition pos)`

Comment: Actually it should work. Did you implement the onCameraChange method manually? Then you might have forgotten the @Override annotation.

Comment: I have set an OnCamaraChangeListener and it works. So ... Thank you.